# How to remove a (plugin) jail from FreeNAS

Tags: freebsd, jails, freenas

I'm running FreeNAS (v9.2.1.9) as a file and media server and have several jails installed, some of them as plugin jails others as "standard" jails.
After I had replaced one of the plugin jails by a "standard" (hand made) jail, I wanted to remove the old plugin jail. I rushed ahead by just deleting the dataset on which the plugin jail was installed, but the plugin jail is still showing up in the web interface under the "Jails" tab. So I assume at some place there is still some residuals of the plugin jail left. Since I have no idea what the plugin installer did and there is no built-in way to remove a plugin jail, I'm stuck with this "unclean" removal.

Now I'm wondering, how can I remove a plugin jail from FreeNAS completely? What additional cleanup is required in my case?

Comment: Did you check /etc/jail.conf (if it exists) and /etc/rc.conf for any jail-related lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on FreeNAS 9.3 and could not find a remove button. I got it to disappear by going to the jails volume, and removing the directory which held the jail:

```
# rm -fr /mnt/black/jails/.couchpotato_1.meta/
```

This also removed the complaints during boot. No negative side effects seen yet.

Comment: Indeed, there was a *.meta directory left which was named after the plugin jail which I had previously deleted. After removing the .meta directory the web UI no longer shows the plugin jail I wanted to get rid of. I'm just wondering if there are more residuals like this left throughout the system...

Answer (score 2):

From the 9.30 GUI, go to `Plugins`, then click the `installed tab` (the default tab is `All`), then select and hit `delete` on the jail that you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I found that FreeNAS 9.10 does not release storage resources manually attached to the jail. This can be observed from the top menu->jails->storage, where the deleted jail from the removed plugin is listed along with the storage that was attached to it. It can be deleted from this list by selecting it and pressing the delete button.

If this storage list is not deleted, then if/when the same plugin is installed, FreeNAS will use the old storage assignments.